# Declare Global Object Inside Function C++

Tags: c++, function, arduino, global-variables

Suppose there is the following code to initialize an LCD display on an Arduino board:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

void LCDInit(){
    LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
}

void LCDPrint(String data){
    lcd.print(data);
}
```

When I call `LCDInit()` it will initialize the LCD display connected to the Arduino.

If I try to print some text onto the LCD in a separate function (e.g. `LCDPrint()`), it won't work, because the `lcd` object is declared in a separate function, `LCDInit()`.

My question is how can I make the `lcd` object *global*, so that referencing it in a separate function will work?

You can do this easily in Python with the `global` keyword, so how can it be done in C++?

Comment: Move the declaration outside the function.

Comment: Does `LiquidCrystal` have a default constructor? Or at least a method to re-initialize it? If not, then you will have to create it dynamically at runtime via `new` to make this work

Comment: @S.M. I would do that, but the reason I'm putting it inside a function is because I don't want it to be initialized as soon as the Arduino starts running (or at all) unless `LCDInit()` is called.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, it doesn't. The values it takes correspond to pins on the Arduino board (which can vary depending on how the user connects the LCD display) so as a result it has no default configuration.

Comment: @pigeonburger "*I don't want it to be initialized as soon as the Arduino starts running (or at all) unless LCDInit() is called*" - all the more reason to use `new`.

Comment: You can't do that in Python either. `global` does not add anything to the global namespace, it only instructs Python to look for a variable there. If there isn't one, you get a runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<LiquidCrystal> lcd;

void LCDInit(){
    lcd = std::make_unique<LiquidCrystal>(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
    lcd->begin(16, 2);
    lcd->setCursor(0, 0);
}

void LCDPrint(String data){
    lcd->print(data);
}
```

**UPDATE**: If you can't use `std::unique_ptr`, then just use `new`/`delete` manually, eg:

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal* lcd = nullptr;

void LCDInit(){
    lcd = new LiquidCrystal(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
    lcd->begin(16, 2);
    lcd->setCursor(0, 0);
}

void LCDCleanup(){
    delete lcd; lcd = nullptr;
}

void LCDPrint(String data){
    lcd->print(data);
}
```

Comment: This won't compile on Arduino (*fatal error: memory: No such file or directory*) I don't believe Arduino supports it. Are there no other ways?

Comment: Try something like https://github.com/smeshlink/Arduino-Plus/blob/master/hardware/tools/g%2B%2B_arm_none_eabi/arm-none-eabi/include/c%2B%2B/4.4.1/bits/unique_ptr.h Otherwise, you will just have to use `new`/`delete` manually, which means adding a `LCDCleanup()` function.

Comment: Thank you - It can compile now! So when do I have to call `LCDCleanup()`? (sorry, I'm new to C++ and am using it so I can make a serial-communication Arduino API with Python) I just wanna be 100% sure of everything

Comment: @pigeonburger obviously, you would have to call `LCDCleanup()` before/during program shutdown.

Comment: Ah yeah, to delete it from memory, I understand. It works for me thank you!

Comment: there is no before shutdown on Arduino. it runs only one program